# Running shell script from php and then php script from shell, can't get it to work

Tags: php, bash, shell, exec

I'm running an `.sh` script from php with `exec` (tried `shell_exec` and `passthru` too) and appending the command with `> /dev/null 2>&1 &` so the php script frees up the browser. Then in the shell script I'm running another php file and capturing the response of that php file into a variable. The shell script ends up calling index.php on the server instead of the supplied php file.

Here's my php command to run the shell script:

`exec(BASE.'/../shellfile.sh '.$arg1.' '.$arg2.' '.$arg3.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &');`

And here's my command to run a php file from the shell script:

`VAR1=$(php -q $BASE/processingfile.php $FOLDER/temp.txt)`

Side notes:

`BASE` is defined in PHP script and `$arg1`, `$arg2` and `$arg3` are defined variables.

`VAR1`, `BASE` and `FOLDER` are defined in the shell script.

I tried running `BASE.'/../shellfile.sh '.$arg1.' '.$arg2.' '.$arg3.' > /dev/null 2>&1 &'` from Putty with SSH and it works well. It includes correct file instead of `index.php` if ran directly from SSH.

So this is the logic: PHP -> Run shell file and free-up browser, Shell -> Run PHP file and capture response.

Shell script ends up calling `index.php` on the server instead of `processingfile.php`. Besides, PHP headers like `X-Powered-By: PHP/5.X.XX` are returned to shell script from `index.php` and saved into the `VAR1` shell variable.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Additional notes:

- First PHP file is located below public folder, whereas the shell script and `processingfile.php` are located above the public folder
- I have an .htaccess file in public folder, but not above public
- `shellfile.sh` and `processingfile.php` are chmoded 777.

Comment: Please make edits to your question instead of putting further details in the comments section.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to change from the default directory (e.g the directory where index.php is) to the directory to where you want to script to run. For example, use a command similar to this to tell php where to look for the script.

```
exec("cd path/to/file && sh ./yourScript.sh);
```